# BarEditItem1, what is the code to access to a combox item

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, devexpress

In my form I have a Barmanager, in which I have a comboboxedit1. I want to know how to access to the selected item of the baredititem1 (combobox). In the normal combobox it is:

```
dim q =combobox1.selecteditem
```

but I can't do the same in a baredititem1 wgich is placed in a barmanager.

Answer (score 1):

You can grab the current selected value using the `barEditItem1.EditValue` property, or while the editor is activated, you can access the current editor instance by `BarManager.ActiveEditor` property, which you should cast to `ComboBoxEdit` in your case. You can read about this more [in the documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#windowsforms/DevExpressXtraBarsBarManager_ActiveEditortopic), where they explain why you cannot access the concrete editor anytime you want.